# HTML JavaScript - Issues with form with extra/optional fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that reveals extra fields if the user chooses 'yes' from the select input. These extra fields are both required unless the user chooses 'no', in which case the fields are hidden and the required attribute is removed. It works, however I've encountered an issue where if the user selects 'yes', and then reverts back to 'no', then the form won't submit, presumably because it is not removing the required attribute and still expects the fields to be filled in. If anyone could help fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form id="auth_form" method="post" action="action.php">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Defect?</label>
    <select class="select form-control" id="defect" name="defect">
      <option id="No" value="No">No</option>
      <option id="Yes" value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="extra" name="extra" style="display: none">

    <label class="control-label" for="desc">Description</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="desc" name="desc" required disabled>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback" name="auth_code" id="auth_code">
      <label for="auth_code10" class="control-label">
        Authorisation Code</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="auth_code_input" autocomplete="new-password" name="auth_code_input" type="password" required disabled>
      <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon" id="iconBad"></span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Submit
    </button>
  </div>

</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#defect").on("change", checkIfYes);

  // Functions

  function checkIfYes() {
    if (document.getElementById('defect').value == 'Yes') {

      // show extra fields & make them required
      document.getElementById('extra').style.display = '';
      document.getElementById('auth_code_input').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('desc').disabled = false;

      $('#auth_code_input').blur(function() { // validate the extra fields
        if (!ValidateInput()) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });

      $('#auth_form').on('submit', function(e) { // validate the extra fields
        if (!ValidateInput()) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      })

    } else { // hide and disable extra fields so form can submit
      document.getElementById('extra').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('auth_code_input').disabled = true;
      document.getElementById('desc').disabled = true;
    }

  }

  function ValidateInput() {
    var code = ['Foo', 'Bar']; // user must enter one of these
    var IsValid = false;
    var input = $('#auth_code_input').val()

    if (code.indexOf(input) > -1) { // if input equals one of the codes in the array
      $('#iconBad').removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
      IsValid = true;
    } else {
      $('#iconBad').removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
      IsValid = false;
    }

    return IsValid;
  }

});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sinesine/cvvcwoom/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if (document.getElementById('defect').value == 'Yes') {
//.....
  $('#auth_form').on('submit', function(e) { // validate the extra fields
    if (!ValidateInput()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
```

if user clicks **yes** `#auth_form` binds to a function that prevents the submit. But after click on **NO** there is no method to change it back.

```
if (document.getElementById('defect').value == 'No') {
   $('#auth_form').off('submit');
});
```